# Complex objects using room - Android

Tags: android, android-room

I just started using Room library for database and I figured out that it is more complicated to put an object in the table. I made a diagram to demonstrate the situation in my app:

[image]

I could insert the Workout object into my table, but I have to create `Converters` to simplify the Exercise List object.

I also would like to create a table for Exercises that have the Workline List objects..
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking how to store List<Worklines> in a field? You already answered that yourself: using Converters. Are you asking how to use a Converter?

Comment: @m0skit0 yeah, how can I use a converter on List<Exercises>?

Comment: You can serilize it (e.g. Java's serialization, JSON, YAML...) then store it, and deserialize for retrieving.

Comment: I did it, using gson. But, everytime I want to update exersice or workline object I have to update the whole Workout object.

Comment: Why you have to update Workout if you only want to update Exercise? That's a logic mistake in your program and has nothing to do with your question.